# Javascript: Using prompt dialogue box in loop and test data against each regular expression

Tags: javascript

In my javascript program I have created four regular expression and created prompt in loop in order ask input from user. When user enter any data it should check against all regular expression I created and Display whether "It's a match" or "No match" after each test and it Repeat until the user enter "stop" and test the last time and exit. One prompt check as and display match likewise. My code is almost ready But due to some error my code in not working properly. Can anyone correct me ?

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>lab12</title>

</head>
<body bgcolor="#efe862">
    <h3 id="txt1">  </h3>
    <p id= "text1"> </p>
    <p id="match1"></p>
    <p id="noMatch1"></p>

    <p id= "text2"> </p>
    <p id="match2"></p>
    <p id="noMatch2"></p>

    <p id= "text3"> </p>
    <p id="match3"></p>
    <p id="noMatch3"></p>

    <p id= "text4"> </p>
    <p id="match4"></p>
    <p id="noMatch4"></p>

        <script>
            myFunction();
        function myFunction() {

            var prom = prompt("Enter a text(stop to exit)");

            var patt1 = /\w/g;
            var patt2 = /\[^0-9]/g;  
            var patt3 = /[A-Z][a-z]\s/;
            var patt4 = /\W\d\d\d\d\d.?\d/;

            while(prom !== "stop"){
                var prom = prompt("Enter a text(stop to exit)");
            }

            do{

            document.getElementById("txt1").innerHTML = "The text is: " + prom;

            document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = "Match a string that contains atleast one character in A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and _";

            if(patt1 || patt2 || patt3 || patt4.test(prom)){
            document.getElementById("match1").innerHTML = "It's match";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("noMatch1").innerHTML = "No match";
            }

            document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = "Match a string that doesn't contain a number between 0 and 9";

            if(patt1 || patt2 || patt3 || patt4.test(prom)){
            document.getElementById("match2").innerHTML = "It's match";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("noMatch2").innerHTML = "No match";
            }

            document.getElementById("text3").innerHTML = "Search for an uppercase letter, followed by one or more lower case letters, followed by a space";

            if(patt1 || patt2 || patt3 || patt4.test(prom)){
            document.getElementById("match3").innerHTML = "It's match";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("noMatch3").innerHTML = "No match";
            }

            document.getElementById("text4").innerHTML = "Find a # sign, followed by exactly 5 repeating digits, a period and another digit";

            if(patt1 || patt2 || patt3 || patt4.test(prom)){
            document.getElementById("match4").innerHTML = "It's match";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("noMatch4").innerHTML = "No match";
            }

            }
        }
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

expected output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `do/while loop`, but in a wrong way. Try it like this:

```
var prom = prompt("Enter a text(stop to exit)");

while (prom !== "stop") {
    // rest of the function...
    prom = prompt("Enter a text(stop to exit)");
}
```

Note that there is just one `prom` variable declaration (`var prom = ...`), you can not do this again in the code, as that would declare new variable (in your example in different scope), so the original `prom` variable value would stay unchanged.

Also you are checking the regexps wrongly, you can not do `if (patt1 || patt2 || patt3 || patt4.test(prom)) {`, that would check if variable `patt1` is true (which is as it is defined regexp). You want to run the `re.test()` for all of the regexps:

`if (patt1.test(prom) || patt2.test(prom) || patt3.test(prom) || patt4.test(prom)) {`

Something like this should

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>lab12</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#efe862">
<h3 id="txt1"></h3>
<p id="text1"></p>
<p id="match1"></p>
<p id="noMatch1"></p>

<p id="text2"></p>
<p id="match2"></p>
<p id="noMatch2"></p>

<p id="text3"></p>
<p id="match3"></p>
<p id="noMatch3"></p>

<p id="text4"></p>
<p id="match4"></p>
<p id="noMatch4"></p>

<script>
    myFunction();

    function myFunction() {
        var patt1 = /\w/g;
        var patt2 = /\[^0-9]/g;
        var patt3 = /[A-Z][a-z]\s/;
        var patt4 = /\W\d\d\d\d\d.?\d/;
        var prom = prompt("Enter a text(stop to exit)");

        while (prom !== 'stop') {
            if (prom === "stop") {
                return;
            }

            document.getElementById("txt1").innerHTML = "The text is: " + prom;
            document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = "Match a string that contains atleast one character in A-Z, a-z, 0-9 and _";

            if (patt1.test(prom)) {
                document.getElementById("match1").innerHTML = "It's match";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("noMatch1").innerHTML = "No match";
            }

            document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = "Match a string that doesn't contain a number between 0 and 9";

            if (patt2.test(prom)) {
                document.getElementById("match2").innerHTML = "It's match";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("noMatch2").innerHTML = "No match";
            }

            document.getElementById("text3").innerHTML = "Search for an uppercase letter, followed by one or more lower case letters, followed by a space";

            if (patt3.test(prom)) {
                document.getElementById("match3").innerHTML = "It's match";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("noMatch3").innerHTML = "No match";
            }

            document.getElementById("text4").innerHTML = "Find a # sign, followed by exactly 5 repeating digits, a period and another digit";

            if (patt4.test(prom)) {
                document.getElementById("match4").innerHTML = "It's match";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("noMatch4").innerHTML = "No match";
            }

            prom = prompt("Enter a text(stop to exit)");
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should I write this in function or outside of function ?

Comment: I am still not getting. Can you please write code ? Thanks

Comment: How should I apply re.test() ?

Comment: How to apply re.test() ? I am checking it wrongly. How should I check one entered value against each ?

Comment: If statement with multiple or clauses is ok, you just need to use `re.test()` every time to evaluate the regexp. I noted that in the answer, just use `if (patt1.test(prom) || patt2.test(prom) || patt3.test(prom) || patt4.test(prom)) {` to check all 4 regexps.

Comment: Why we need prompt at last ?

Comment: To get the response of user, to know is they want to continue. The prompt in the end of cycle basically gives us new value (from the new prompt).

Comment: Btw I might misunderstand why you are trying to accomplish. If you want to display in first paragraph that the first regexp matches, and in 2nd that the 2nd regexp matches, you just need to check that regexp and ignore others.

Comment: After entering value in first prompt it should display and check against all Regex and then another prompt should be generated

Comment: and When user enter stop in prompt it should stop and check stop value

Comment: So after first prompt how to display and check value ?

Comment: Well if you want to do it "step by step", meaning that there will be some delay between the first prompt so user can see the results first, you need to do it in a different way. Not sure what you really want to achieve.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156709/discussion-between-pari-and-martin-adamek).